# Ruby on Rails - modifying part of embedded Ruby in .js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, web

I'm working on a single-page site and have gotten the ajax loading of templates to insert into the content part of the site working. However, I'm having trouble doing this with multiple templates, using a parameter.

I have 5 templates, shared/blog, shared/projects, etc.

In my controller, I'm doing an AJAX call to 'replace'

```
pages = ['blog', 'projects', 'resume', 'gallery', 'contact']

def replace
  @content = params[:content]
  if not pages.include? content
    content = 'blog'
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In replace.js.erb, I have this code:

```
$(".content_inner").html("<%= j render(:partial => 'shared/blog') %>");
```

I have kept it just saying 'shared/blog' because it works for loading the blog if I keep the embedded Ruby static like that. However, I can't figure out how to replace the 'blog' part of 'shared/blog' in here to whatever is in the @content variable. I've tried things like #{content}, but to no avail.

(It does receive the content variable correctly, the issue is just with using it)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation requires double quotes. You're after:

```
$(".content_inner").html("<%= j render("shared/#{@content}") %>");
```

A few notes:

- The `:partial =>` hasn't been necessary for *years* in Rails. Just use `render <partial_name>`.
- Rails already comes with a place to store your shared partials: `app/views/application`. You should move your shared partials there, and then you can render them simply by using `render(@content)`. This is important to how Rails works, because it allows you to override the partial in controller-specific view paths. For example, calling `render("blog")` will render `app/views/<controller_name>/blog.js.erb` if it exists, and then fallback to `app/views/application/blog.js.erb` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked! Kinda new to RoR so didn't think to do that.